# Dynamic Float Format Specifier in C

Tags: c, floating-point, string-formatting, format-specifiers

Is there any way to have a user inputed float format specifier?
For example, if I print this.

```
float c = 15.0123
printf("%.2f", c);

// outputs: 15.01
```

How can I assign the number of decimal places to a variable? Like:

```
int n = 3;
float c = 15.0123
printf("%.(%i)f", n, c);

// outputs: 15.012
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The precision can be specified by an argument with the asterisk `*`. This is called an argument-supplied precision.

```
float c = 15.0123;
int m = 2;
printf("%.*f", m,  c);
```

Comment: And if I have several arguments I want to print with different precision ?

Answer (score 7):

`printf("%.*f", n, c);` that will print out c with n places after the decimal.