# how to do rounding in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

I have a code sample:

```
float f = 3.55f;
printf("%.1f\n", f);
```

the result is 3.5, not 3.6, which is desired.

```
float delta = 1e-7;
float f = 3.55f;
printf("%.1f\n", f+delta);
```

now the result is 3.6, but when f is 0.0499999f;

```
printf("%.1f\n", f+delta);
```

result turns out to be 0.1, not 0.0.

I need a function that transforms 3.55 to 3.6,  0.0499999 to 0.0, anybody give a clue?

Comment: Try this functions http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html

Comment: In the second example, are you sure that merely declaring another variable changes the behavior of `printf()`?

Comment: Try adding one half of the desired precision, e.g. `f + 0.05`, and then print with `%.1f` (or 0.005 and `%.2f`, etc.).

Comment: By the way, `.1f` prints `.1f`, there's a `%` missing.

Comment: Do enable warnings when you compile your code, the compiler would have warned you about that missing '%'. Under Linux with gcc it printed `warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]`, clearly something wrong on that line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manually implementing a rounding function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525891/manually-implementing-a-rounding-function-in-c)

Comment: +1 for have a nice short clear explanation of the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

As with many floating-point issues, the problem is that your value [isn't really 3.55](http://ideone.com/zcWgtB):

```
float f = 3.55f;
printf("%.10f\n", f);  // 3.5499999523
```

See also http://floating-point-gui.de/.

So unless you use `ceil()`, this value will never be rounded up.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of [this answer to a related question by H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12525956/315052) yields the desired output:

```
float custom_round(float num, int prec)
{
    float trunc = round(num * pow(10, prec+7));
    trunc = round(trunc/pow(10, 7));
    return trunc / pow(10, prec);
}
```

The `7` extra precision is derived from the `delta` value. I don't think it is generally applicable, but for the two numbers `3.55f` and `0.0499999f`, it points to a position that the first number will round up while the second number will round down.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that the decimal values in the example have no exact binary equivalents.

Then there is the delta:

1. Having a decimal delta will probably mess up your rounding as adding one unrepresentable number to another is less than optimal.
2. The delta should be based on a binary value on the order of 1/(2^23) of 2^the exponent of the number displayed (single precision) or 1/(2^52) (double precision).

For a single precision number x in the range 16 <= x < 32 (exponent = 4) the delta should be 2^(4-23) or 2^-19.

Answer (score 0):

Q: ... function that transforms 3.55 to 3.6, 0.0499999 to 0.0 ...?
A: Using @Kninnug answer, but to 1 decimal place.

```
f = round(f * 10) / 10.0;
```

It will give you `3.5` because the number `f` is *not* originally 3.55.  True, you initialized `f` using the text "3.55", but `C` and your computer were unable to exactly represent that number.  **There is no (float) 3.55 on your system**.  Instead `f` has a value about `3.549999952...` as it is the closest choice.

Should you *still* want to show `f` rounded to 3.6 rather than 3.5, you need to nudge `f` up a bit.  Nudging when it is `3.549999952...` so it has a value >= 3.55 and when `f` is `0.04999990016...` (0.0499999 is not exactly representable either) that the same nudging keeps it `f` < 0.5.

The smallest we can increase `f` and see a change is `nextafterf(f, g)`.   `g` is the value you wish to move toward.

```
3.549999952...   --> 3.550000190...
0.04999990016... --> 0.04999990389...

printf("%.1f\n", nextafterf(f, 2*f));
// prints 3.6 when f is 3.549999952...
// prints 0.0 when f is 0.04999990389...
```

Recommend you review the reference in @Oli Charlesworth answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here this code works. I commented the code so you could understand it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    float delta = 1e-7;
    float f = 3.55f;

    // Here we minus f (3.55) from the integer of f (3) so 3.55 - 3 = 0.55
    // Then we check whether the value is bigger than 0.5
    if( (f-(int)f) >= 0.5 ) { 
            // If it is, then plus 0.01 to the answer. Thus making it 3.65
        f = f + 0.01;
    } else {
            // If its not, minus 0.01 from the answer.
            // Assuming f is 3.44 this will make f 3.43
        f = f - 0.01;
    }

    // Since you its to the first decimal place, the code above will output 
    // your desired result which is 3.6.
    printf("%.1f\n", f+delta);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you. Here's a full program to round but you can use the function only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

//function prototypes
float roundon(float n,int to);

void main(){
    //vars
    float num;
    int roundto;
    puts("Enter the decimal to be rounded");
    scanf("%f",&num);

    puts("Enter the number of decimal places to be rounded");
    scanf("%d",&roundto);

    float rounded= roundon(num,roundto);
    printf("The rounded value is %f\n",rounded);
}

//functions
float roundon(float n, int to){
    //vars
    float rounded;

    int checker=(int) (n*pow(10,(to+1)))%10;
    int dec= (int) (n*pow(10,to));
    if(checker>=5){
        dec++;
    }

    rounded= (float) dec/(pow(10,to));
    return (rounded);
}
```

Comment: Enter the decimal to be rounded
523.567
Enter the number of decimal places to be rounded
2
The rounded value is 523.570007  (This was my output with the above program but i am not sure where the trailing 00007 came from, but you could work that out. Anyway i was using Linux and you might have used some other OS)