# Dynamic Float Formatter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, format

I want to be able to specify the formatter for float, ints etc. dynamically. See example below:

```
float myF = 19.43;
float numOfDecimals = 3;

myF.ToString($"F{numOfDecimals}");   // should print: '19.430'

string customFormatter = "E2";

myF.ToString($"{customFormatter}");   // should print the exponential form i.e. '1.94E1'
```

[You can do this in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627075/dynamic-float-format-specifier-in-c). Can you do this in C#?

Comment: Did you try this? There's no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes I did. It print 'F3'.

Comment: No it doesn't...https://repl.it/repls/TroubledWorrisomeCone